# Wifi symbol always show exclamation mark since Lollipop upgrade

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, google-account, motorola-moto-g

Since getting the recent Lollipop upgrade, the wifi symbol always has an exclamation mark. Wifi seems to work fine, and I gather this symbol means something to do with inability to access Google services - but I use Google Inbox, and that works fine, too. I also understand that this symbol corresponds to the red-shaded wifi symbol of Kit-Kat, but I didn't have that persistently.

So what's going on? It's just slightly annoying.

Motorola Moto G, early 2014.

Comment: Might have something to do with this: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/100657/1465

Comment: Yeah, that answer offers a way to disable the "captive portal detection" - although I think it requires root to implement. It doesn't offer any insight into why I'm having the problem though.