# Lollipop 5.1 doesn't automatically connect to wi-fi

Tags: wi-fi, 5.1-lollipop

After I upgraded my Nexus 5 to Lollipop 5.1, it does not automatically connect to wi-fi because Google is blocked in China and then the phone treated it as no network connection.

I have tried the solution here: [How to disable captive portal detection? How to remove exclamation mark on Wi-Fi or signal icon in Lollipop?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/100657/how-to-disable-captive-portal-detection-how-to-remove-exclamation-mark-on-wi-fi)

However, it only removed the exclamation mark besides the wi-fi signal symbol, but the phone still won't connect to that wi-fi automatically.

Comment: Could you clarify whether this issue affects *all* WiFi access points, or only those that use captive portals? The linked question seems to say so, but clarification is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Android 5.1 upgrade on MotoX.

What worked for me 
- switched off WLAN > restarted the router > switched on WLAN

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

Settings→ Wi-Fi→ Advanced in Upper-right corner→ Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep→ Always.
It'll work out.

Comment: That hasn't a single thing to do with captive portals. Have you read more than just the title of the question? ;) It's not about *keeping the connection active* (which your post would be an answer to), but about *establishing* it in the first place without requiring user interaction.