# Phone uses 3G even when connected to WiFi

Tags: cyanogenmod, wi-fi, motorola-moto-g, 3g, proxy

I've a `Moto-G XT1033`. When I connect the phone to WiFi, it connects fine, shows the WiFi icon but uses 3G for internet. H+ or E is shown over mobile signal icon and an exclamation mark on WiFi.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: shoes H+ when on 3G]

I've to manually disable mobile data to force the phone to use WiFi. Then it works just fine.

Here's with data disabled

[image]

Also, this problem appeared only after I upgraded from kitkat to lollipop official ROM. Now I've switched to CM12 but the problem persists.

My WiFi uses proxy to connect to the internet and this problem is **only on WiFi networks that use proxy.**

Any idea what causes this or how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just [disable captive portal detection](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/100657). In the terminal, or in `adb shell`, issue the command

```
settings put global captive_portal_detection_enabled 0
```

and reboot.

Comment: my device api is 15  and when I try this I get this error `sh: settings: not found`