# How to disable captive portal login detection on Android M

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, wifi-hotspot, authorization, captive-portal

I would like to know if it possible to disable the captive portal detection required by my WIFI HotsPot of my company. I found [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/100657/how-to-disable-captive-portal-detection-how-to-remove-exclamation-mark-on-wi-fi), the solution of which should remove the WIFI notification for enter the login / password of the captive portal. May be I didn't understand well the problem due my poor English skill. I don't want to transform my Android Box to a new WIFI HotSpot Box. Rather, I want to connect my Android system to the WIFI captive portal of my company. However I applied the booth solution of the question  above. No issue as all the ping to outside are lost, and the system still isolated from the network. Everything it's working with an authentication.
When I'm connecting to the HotSpot of my company, the status is : Connected, No Internet.

As the Android Box has been declared to pass through without any authentication on my WIFI network, my system should not ask for any login and password, the MAC address should be the identification only

Thanks for any help

Comment: The question you linked to already answers perfectly. I reckon that's still a problem with your network setup.

Comment: I corrected the meaning of my question with more detail (Hoping)

Comment: I see no difference: the captive portal problem at the core remains the same, and the only solution is still there, which you've already applied. I stand by my original opinion.

Comment: what's side do you thing is the problem on the android box or on the wifi of the company? thanks

Comment: To determine this, try letting another Android device through in the same way you did to the box. Can that device access the internet without the portal popping up?

Comment: Hi Andy,  It's working with  Android Kitkat MINIX devices. The network service told me the rules has been cloned with MAC address exception.