# Stop navigating to google.com for wifi sign-in?

Tags: wi-fi, settings, chrome-for-android, networking, google-settings

My device (unrooted samsung s5, latest google chrome browser version) keeps navigating to https://www.google.com to (eventually) access a public wifi's login page. This is problematic of course as the actual wifi "sign-in" page (that I'm supposed to be forwarded to, or the http redirection for it) is obviously not signed by an ssl certificate for www.google.com, so I get the expected ssl error message.

Is there some setting I can change to change the default wifi sign-in address for the android chrome browser?

Comment: Refer to answers below [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/100657/how-to-disable-captive-portal-detection-how-to-remove-exclamation-mark-on-wi-fi) for how to change the captive portal server, or how to disable the mechanism altogether.

Comment: Just guessing as I played with those settings last night. The setting is most likely `captive_portal_http_url`. Not sure if it can be set without root e.g. via `adb shell`, but it the syntax would be `settings put global captive_portal_http_url http://www.example.com/page` (of course replacing the URL by yours). [See here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-8.0.0_r4/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java#8795) for the other settings. To reset: `settings global delete captive_portal_http_url`. Use `settings global get` to check the original setting first ;)

Comment: @Izzy It's possible to set it without a root shell, I do it on new devices I set up.

Comment: Thanks, @AndyYan – did you also play with the URL parts, to define a "custom portal server"? And if so, using http or the https variant? If someone succeeded with that, it would make a good and interesting answer! Some detailed description of those parameters (and their usage) would also be nice. But I guess that should [go to a different question](/q/186993/16575) I've just posted (I don't want to hijack this one ;)

Comment: Since the default Google server is unreachable in China, I have to define a custom URL. I only had to do the https command to make it work. Thing is, I feel the original question I linked to already has some answers that explains the whole mechanism quite nicely, only the command to set the URL wasn't updated for Nougat (`captive_portal_http(s)_url` instead of `captive_portal_server`). I'll sum up some info I can find and see if it's worthy of an answer over there.